# How to make exception handler called from Project Reactor 3 flatMapMany?

Tags: java, project-reactor

In the following code, I want to get the list of products for the specified type Id.
If the specified type does not exist, I want to return a 404 code as response for the request.

Endpoint :

```
Get("/products/{typeId}/products")
@Operation(description = "Returns the products of the specified type.")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "List of products.")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "type Id does not exist.")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Error.")
public Flux<Asset> findProductsByTypeId(long typeId) {
    return typeService.findType(typeId)
            .flatMapMany(
                    type -> {
                        LOGGER.info("On success!");
                        return typeService.findProductsByTypeId(typeId);
                    },
                    error -> {
                        LOGGER.info("On error!");
                        Flux.error(() -> new TypeException(typeId)); 
                    },
                    null);
}
```

Exception handler :

```
@Singleton
@Requires(classes = TypeException.class)
public class TypeExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler<TypeException, HttpResponse<JsonError>> {
    @Override
    public HttpResponse<JsonError> handle(HttpRequest request, TypeException exception) {
        return HttpResponse.<JsonError>notFound(new JsonError(exception.getMessage())
                .link(Link.SELF, Link.of(request.getUri())));
    }
}
```

In case that the type exist, the result is as expected (200 code with the products list), but when the type
does not exist, the exception does not trigger the expected response code (404).

I tried to replace

```
Flux.error(() -> new TypeException(typeId));
```

by

```
throw new TypeException(typeId);
```

but it got the same result

Comment: What does `typeService.findType(typeId)` do when no records are found? Does it perhaps return an empty flux?

Comment: @adnan_e typeService.findType(typeId) retunrs a Mon<Type>. Here is its code  :  public Mono<Type> findType(long typeId) {
        return Mono.defer(()
                -> Mono.justOrEmpty(doFindType(typeId).orElseThrow(()
                -> new TypeException(typeId))));
    }

Comment: doFindType(typeId) rerurns an Optional<Type>

Comment: Instead of using flatMapMany(onNext, onError, onComplete), I tried flamMapMany(onNex) combbined with returnOnError(value), I'am surprised that now it only consider the onErrorRetunr operator, the process non longer enter  the faltMapMany operator ! consequently the endponit now always return an error even if the type does exist. Here is the code :

Comment: public Flux<Type> findProductsByTypeId(long typeId) {
        return typeService.findType(typeId)
                .flatMapMany(type -> typeService
                        .findProductsByTypeId(typeId))
                .onErrorReturn(new ArrayList<Asset>()
                        .stream()
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new TypeException(typeId)));

    }

Answer (score 0):

Apparently project reactor can't handle more than one flux at time.
Instead of searching the type first, I create a method that check if the type exist (its retun type is a boolean not a flux thats the key point). Accorgind to the check result, I return either the products flux or throw the exception.

Here is the new code that works for me :

```
Get("/products/{typeId}/products")
@Operation(description = "Returns the products of the specified type.")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "List of products.")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "type Id does not exist.")
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Error.")
public Flux<Asset> findProductsByTypeId(long typeId) {
    return typeExist(typeId)
            ? typeService.findProductsByTypeId(typeId)
            : Flux.error(() -> new TypeException(typeId));
}
```